# How to solve Formtastic input error in Active Admin when creating a new entry in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, formtastic

When wanting to make a new entry to a model in Active Admin, I click on the action button "Create new New Employer". I then get this error message:

Formtastic::UnknownInputError in Admin::Employers#new

Unable to find input class BinaryInput

```
@input_class_finder.find(as)
  rescue Formtastic::InputClassFinder::NotFoundError
    raise Formtastic::UnknownInputError, "Unable to find input #{$!.message}"
  end

  # @api private
```

Comment: Maybe some more code will help in suggesting an answer. Like active admin code for `new` action.

Comment: where can I find the code?

Answer (score 2):

@Nikita, first of all please read the docs https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/tree/68d50d4221976df9d42e5d670b0877770ca8eeef/docs this will answer on most of your questions.

ActiveAdmin by default renders all the columns of your database table to display the form and  is not able to show this particular one
because there is no option to handle binary column( check, there is a binary typed column in your employers table)

so there are 2 options

1) override you form declaration how it described here
    https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/68d50d4221976df9d42e5d670b0877770ca8eeef/docs/5-forms.md

and use `as: :string` options for your column if you need to display it at all.

2) it is possible also to create custom input to do this add initializer with such source that may not be your case.

```
 class BinaryInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput

 end
```

Answer (score 2):

### Workaround

This worked for me: create a file below and it will solve the error.

```
# app/inputs/inet_input.rb
class InetInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
end
```

> In this case replace `inet` with `BinaryInput`

### Reason

The possible problem is, `Formtastic` is unable to map the column type to HTML input types.

> this solution is tested with formtastic (~> 3.1)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem editing a `User` resource which, when created by Devise, has

`t.inet "current_sign_in_ip"`

column type.

If you are fine to change the data type from `inet` to `string` simply generate a migration:

`rails g migration ChangeDatabaseColumnTypeForIpAddressesInUsers`

```
class ChangeDatabaseColumnTypeForIpAddressesInUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_column :users, :current_sign_in_ip, :string
    change_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I came into this problem and didn't like the `StringInput` solution because it is a single line and can't handle line breaks. You can similarly fix this by

```
# ./app/inputs/binary_input.rb
class BinaryInput < Formtastic::Inputs::TextInput
end
```

As seen with in this image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHRex.png